# too many values to unpack (expected 2) - Dictionary to JSON

Tags: python, json, django, post

I have a big dictionary with more than 50 items. I am trying to return this dictionary in the form of JSON.

The code for that is:-

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseData, indent = 0, default=str), content_type="application/json")
```

There are some date fields in the dictionary and so I mentioned default=str to convert them to string.

When I print the json.dumps, I do see proper values present in the json. But when I put it in HttpResponse, I get the below error:-

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Could somebody tell me why exactly its happening and what is the workaround?

EDIT:- TRACEBACK

```
Internal Server Error: /ScApp2/home/App20/Details/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "\PythonWorkspace\ScApp\ScApp2\views.py", line 88, in ModelDetails
    cmsPointScore = PspstCmspointscore.objects.filter(model_id)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 836, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 854, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1253, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1277, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1150, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your query (that's why I asked for the traceback):

```
cmsPointScore = PspstCmspointscore.objects.filter(model_id)
```

You should add the field name to the filter expression, for example:

```
cmsPointScore = PspstCmspointscore.objects.filter(model_id=model_id)
```